Youtube iframe - hide video preview
enter image description hereI am working on a task related to YouTube iframes. I want to hide the thumbnail preview of the video. I have looked for YouTube iframe support functions but couldn't find any.
I tried using JavaScript to hide the thumbnail, but it seems not to work due to CORS. Has anyone encountered this situation before? I would appreciate your help.

That is not possible. Instead you can disable the on screen player controls and enable keyboard controls and also iframe controls.
